# How can an operator funtion in ansible with "set_fact" and "when"

Tags: linux, unix, automation, ansible, redhat

How can I use the set_fact module with "when" to use below conditions? I need "shmall" value to be set depending upon the total memory in a RHEL server.
I need to know how operators work in Ansible.

```
- name: Total Available Memory
shell: cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal | awk '{print $2}'
register: MemTotal

    # for RHEL7,SHMALL Setting should be (PHYSICAL MEMORY – MEMORY FOR SYSTEM) / PAGE SIZE with 4096 pagesize.
- name: SHMALL value to set for memory size less than 16G
set_fact:
    shmall: 3670016
    when: (MemTotal le "16777216") | int
- name: SHMALL value to set for memory size between 16G and 32G
set_fact:
    shmall: 7340032
    when: (MemTotal gt "16777216" and  MemTotal le "33554432") | int
- name: SHMALL value to set for memory size between 32G and 64G
set_fact:
    shmall: 14680064
    when: (MemTotal gt "33554432" and  MemTotal  le "6710886") | int
- name: SHMALL value to set for memory size between 64G and 256G
set_fact:
    shmall: 57671680
    when: (MemTotal  gt "67108864" and  MemTotal  le "268435456") | int
```

Comment: - name: SHMALL value to set for memory size less than 16G
  set_fact:
    shmall: 3670016
    when: ansible_memtotal_mb < 16384
Thanks @Konstantin , I have shmall value already defined. It's the conditional statement is the one i need to make work.
- name: SHMALL value to set for memory size between 16G and 32G
  set_fact:
    shmall: 7340032
    when: ansible_memtotal_mb > 16384 and ansible_memtotal_mb < 32768

- name: SHMALL value to set for memory size between 32G and 64G
  set_fact:
    shmall: 14680064
    when: ansible_memtotal_mb > 32768 and ansible_memtotal_mb < 65536

Comment: - name: oracle-recommended sysctl
  sysctl:
     name: "{{ item.name }}"
     value: "{{ item.value }}"
     sysctl_file: /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf
     ignoreerrors: yes # Ignore errors about unknown keys
  with_items:
     - { name: "kernel.shmall", value: "{{ shmall }}" }

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to get MemTotal from shell, you can get this info from [ansible facts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#information-discovered-from-systems-facts). In this case the fact is called `ansible_memtotal_mb`. Operators in ansible work pretty much like python operators, here is example playbook for my notebook with 3834 total memory.

#### playbook.yml

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ansible_memtotal_mb}}"

    - debug: msg="It's over 9000!!"
      when: ansible_memtotal_mb > 9000

    - debug: msg="It's too weak, lesser than 9000"
      when: ansible_memtotal_mb < 9000

    - debug: msg="It's between 3000 and 4000"
      when: ansible_memtotal_mb > 3000 and ansible_memtotal_mb < 4000
```

#### Output

```
ansible-playbook -i localhost, playbook.yml

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": 3834
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "It's too weak, lesser than 9000"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "It's between 3000 and 4000"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

**Edit:** Added tasks, as asked in question. You don't need to convert memtotal to KB, it's easier to convert you constraints to MBs

```
- name: SHMALL value to set for memory size less than 16G
  set_fact:
      shmall: 3670016
      when: ansible_memtotal_mb < 16384

- name: SHMALL value to set for memory size between 16G and 32G
  set_fact:
      shmall: 7340032
      when: ansible_memtotal_mb > 16384 and ansible_memtotal_mb < 32768

- name: SHMALL value to set for memory size between 32G and 64G
  set_fact:
      shmall: 14680064
      when: ansible_memtotal_mb > 32768 and ansible_memtotal_mb < 65536

- name: SHMALL value to set for memory size between 64G and 256G
  set_fact:
      shmall: 57671680
      when: ansible_memtotal_mb > 65536 and ansible_memtotal_mb < 262144
```

Comment: The intention of this section of my playbook is to set the SHMALL value in sysctl.conf file with respect to the physical memory on the server. For that, I need the memory in kb.

Comment: - name: Generate the Memory value in KB
  shell: cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal | awk '{print $2}'
  register: MemTotal

- debug: msg="{{MemTotal}}"

- name: SHMALL value to set for memory size less than 16G
  set_fact:
    #shmall: "{{ (((1000000*ansible_memtotal_mb)/4096)*0.4) | int }}"
    shmall: 3670016
    when: MemTotal < 16777216
- name: SHMALL value to set for memory size between 16G and 32G
  set_fact:
    shmall: 7340032
    when: MemTotal > 16777216 and MemTotal < 33554432

Comment: My requirement of this part of the playbook is;
- Check Total Memory of a Redhat server and calculate it in kb
- when: MemTotal < 16777216 , shmall should be 3670016 updated in  sysconfig file
- when: MemTotal > 16777216 and MemTotal < 33554432, shmall: 14680064 should be updated in a sysconfig file
-when: MemTotal > 33554432 and MemTotal < 67108864, shmall: 14680064 should be updated in a sysconfig file

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate your small value:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    mem_gb: "{{ ansible_memtotal_mb/1024 }}"
    mem_pow2: "{{ 2 | pow(((mem_gb|int|log)/(2|log)) | round(0,'ceil')) }}"
    shmall_calculated: "{{ ((mem_pow2|int)*0.875*1024*1024*1024/4096) | int }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ shmall_calculated }}"
```